# How can I let ESB the endpoint of loadbalancer know the client IP of each access

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I use WSO2 ESB loadbalancer on my web API system now.

such as this : `clients (browser) -> esb server -> application server1,2,3 ...`

Now I have a question that the application running on the application server just know the IP that what the ESB server is.

How can I let the application know the client IP of each access ?

Answer (score 0):

Within ESB you can get like this; (Check [this post](http://vvratha.blogspot.com/2011/11/retriving-clientiphost-within-sequence.html))

```
<property name="clienthost" expression="get-property('REMOTE_HOST')" scope="axis2"/>
```

From the application server side, you can access the axis2message context and retrive the remote address